# How can I get this sqlalchemy query to pull data?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm very new to PostgSQL, sqlalchemy, and manipulating databases in general and I've been stuck on this problem for a little bit.

I have a rather large PostgSQL database I'm trying to pull data from. I have the python and database linked up via FastAPI and I know they are connected correctly. As my first baby steps I figured the first thing I would do is pull one row from a table on the database based on User_ID. There are multiple entries in the table for the same User_ID. My query is as follows:

`def get_user_by_id(db: Session, user_id: int):`

`return db.query(models.UserData).filter(models.UserData.user_id == user_id).first()`

"models" is a file that lays out the way the data is formatted. It is as follows:

`class UserData(Base):`

`__tablename__ = "table_1"`

`user_id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True) timestamp_base=Column(String, index=True) ts_offset_seconds=Column(Integer) data=Column(Integer, index=True)`

I am certain the table name is correct and that there are entries in the table for the user_id I'm passing in. All I want to do right now is successfully pull data from the database, but whenever I run the query from before, the only thing I get is "None".

I am not positive if the datatypes of the columns laid out in models are correct. Could that be an issue?

Any help would be appreciated! I've been treading water on this for some time and once this hurdle is done I think I will be well on my way to being done. Please let me know if you need any more information!

Answer (score 0):

May be it is because of your managing database sessions. you need to use

```
SessionLocal()
```

Also, it is recommended to use `id` field for your model.
consider this approach:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session


class UsrUser(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    data = Column(Integer, index=True)


engine = create_engine('YOUR_POSTGRES_DATABASE_URL', echo=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


def get_get_user_by_id(user_id: int, db: Session = SessionLocal()):
    return db.query(UsrUser).filter(UsrUser.id == user_id).first()
```

you can consider datetime in two way. first

```
created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

and you can use `timestamp` and create an `Integer` field